# Unable to broadcast messages using Flask-socketio and Javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask, socket.io

I'm trying to build a simple chatroom application using Flask and socket-io. When a user types a message and clicks on the submit button, the message should be broadcasted to all users. But in my case, after clicking the submit button the page refreshes and nothing appears. Please help.

I have tried running the Javascript code in the firefox browser console and it works fine there(without forms). But when I submit the form from webpage the problem arises.

here's is some code snippet:

python backend:

```
@socketio.on('send messages')
def vote(data):
    messages = data['messages']
    emit('announce messages', {"messages":messages}, broadcast=True)
```

javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    // Connect to websocket
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    // When connected, configure buttons
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        document.querySelector('#form').onsubmit = () => {
            const messages = document.querySelector('#messages').value;
            socket.emit('send messages', {'messages': messages});
        }
    });

    socket.on('announce messages', data => {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = `${data.messages}`;
        document.querySelector('#push').append(li);
    });    
});
```

HTML form

```
<ul id="push">
    <!--filled by socket.io-->
</ul>
<form id="form">
    <label for="messages">Message:</label>
    <input id="messages" type="text" name="messages">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your form, you have to prevent it from actually submitting by returning False so that the connection doesn't drop out. In your case, page is getting refreshed and therefore you are not able to see the result.

```
socket.on('connect', () => {
        document.querySelector('#form').onsubmit = () => {
            const messages = document.querySelector('#messages').value;
            socket.emit('send messages', {'messages': messages});
            return False
        }
    });
```

Maybe this will do the work.